# Android scrolling issue on Intel App Framework hybrid app

Tags: android, intel-xdk, jqmobi, appframework

I am developing the mobile app and I have this wierd issue regarding scrolling (only on Android build).

1. When I have swipe for sidepanel and try to scroll up/down, the scroll gets broken completely (unusable)
2. When I disable the swipe for sidepanel  using:
   `$.ui.slideSideMenu = false;` 
   ...it all works well (in emulate mode). [b]When I build the application[/b], the scroll gets broken again and its barely usable.

Have in mind that I have put

```
$.feat.nativeTouchScroll=true;
```

in index.html

Any ideas how to resolve choppy scrolling?

Comment: (1) Where are you trying to scroll, On Phone, when you have the side menu open, the scrolling is disabled on main view and only allow scrolling on sidemenu.